# Filter for a QUERY function

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-filter

I need some help here.
So I need a function which imports selected columns from a different sheet out of which one of them contains a specified word but allows you to filter/ignore based on specified words

And here's the example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1brWG_lbvqQUDT5x9ZGmxFKYUu6ByQ56SPi9Y9C21WBQ/edit#gid=1683245951

And this is the QUERY Function: 
**=query(Sheet1!A:F, "SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F where (E contains 'Apple')")**

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Sorry I don't see any `apple` in your sheet

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: I know but my question is not answered the way i wanted it yet, i have added a new comment to the person's reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just use and

The only column containing a different variable is column B. 
So you could use

```
=query(Sheet1!A:F, "SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F where E contains 'Apple' and B contains 'had'")
```

Note:
you do not need the parentheses around `E contains 'Apple'`

Comment: Also, since you are selecting the whole row, you could just say "select * where E contains 'Apple' and B contains 'had'"

Comment: All of your suggestions, answer and comment stand correct. :)

Comment: The formula needs to ignore the specified word in the column, not to list it. 'Contains' doesnt work for us in Column B as we want to avoid that word

Comment: In that case just use not as in: `where not E contains 'Apple'`. You can keep or omit the `and B contains 'had'`. It depends on what you want the results to be.

Comment: use this:=query(Sheet1!A:F, "SELECT * where E contains 'Apple' and B <> 'had'")

Comment: "<>" is equivalent to does not contain or "is not"

Comment: =query(Sheet1!A:F, "SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F where E contains 'Apple' and B <> 'has'")
So we tried your formula and it works the way we want but another question, is there any way to add another word (had) to the Column B?

like we tried:
**=query(Sheet1!A:F, "SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F where E contains 'Apple' and B <> 'has,had'")** 

thanks for the explanation Noelle! now we just need to see is there any way to add another word to Column B?

Comment: yes, you would say, =query(Sheet1!A:F, "SELECT * where E contains 'Apple' and B <> 'has' and B <> 'had'")

Comment: But since your column B only contains those two words, your result will be an empty query. You can test the formula by changing one of the words to something different from has or had

Comment: Noelle is right again :)

Comment: @Cheryl. Please think of your possible scenarios, share a less simplified version of your sheet as described [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) and edit your question. This way all these comments can be avoided and your question will make more sense to future readers.

Comment: Thanks Noelle! 
and thank you too marikamitsos. Sorry about the way i'm phrasing and that it's confusing. I have more words (more than 2 of course) in the actual work sheet which is confidential and i couldn't share but in this example i only gave 2 words i should have made more :) 

But thank you guys, the function solved my question.

Thank you! I will hence mark this as solved. :-)